# Get nested table cell with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I've have following html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<div style="LEFT: 135; WIDTH: 450; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 70">
  <a name="content_begins"></a>
  <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td vAlign="top">
      <table class="PortalGadget" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
          <table cellSpacing="6" cellPadding="0" border="0">
            <form name="authenticator" ACTION="auth-cup" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
              <tr bgColor="#6c8899">
                <td><font face="Trebuchet MS" color="#ffffff">&nbsp;*** You Have Already Logged In ***</font></td>
              </tr>

              <tr height="20">
                <td vAlign="bottom" height="20">
                <font face="Trebuchet MS" size="-1">Context:</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td vAlign="bottom" height="20">
                <font face="Trebuchet MS" size="-1">Username:</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input size="40" name="username"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><font face="Trebuchet MS" size="-1">Password:</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="password" size="40" name="password"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td vAlign="bottom" height="20">
                <font face="Trebuchet MS" size="-1">Destination:</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <input size="40" name="url" value="http://ya.ru/"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!---- Hidden field to identify forward/reverse proxy path ------>
                <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="proxypath" VALUE="forward">
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td vAlign="bottom" align="left">
                <input type="submit" alt="Login" value="Login" border="0" name="loginButton">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="reset" alt="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr height="5">
                <td height="5"><hr SIZE="2"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><font face="Trebuchet MS" size="-1">
                <p>Copyright 1999-2003 Novell, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
                </font></td>
              </tr>
            </form>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get text "You Have Already Logged In" from td. I have this code:

```
Stream str = SendData().GetResponseStream();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(str);
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='PortalGadget']"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found: " + table.Id);
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//table"))
                {

                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("tr");

                    if (cells == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode cell in cells)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("cell: " + cell.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I can't get text "You Have Already Logged In" in code. How to get nested table cells values in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm I found solution seems to me:

```
string value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='PortalGadget']/tr/td/table/tr/td")[0].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

To select Nodes from another Node you have to put a '.' at the start of the XPath.

So `table.SelectNodes("//table")` becomes `table.SelectNodes(".//table")`

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you think is discriminant for this data, but when I look at the HTML, it seems the FONT element with the BGCOLOR set to #ffffff is, so that's the corresponding Html Agility Pack code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourHtmlFile);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//font[@color='#ffffff']");
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
```

will output:

```
&nbsp;*** You Have Already Logged In ***
```